# Arduino to breadboard with LM35 temp sensor

Tags: arduino-uno

I have moved the MCU of the Arduino to a breadboard using these steps https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone then interfaced it with an LM35 temperature sensor to the ADC0. But I can't get proper values from the LM35. I think it's because of the Aref or AVcc. Both are just connected to +5? 
Here is my code:

```c
float tempC;
float reading;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    reading = analogRead(0);
    tempC = (reading * 0.4882815) + 5;
    Serial.print(tempC);
    delay(1000);
}
```

I get hex values and sometime high values. What to do with Aref and AVcc?

**EDIT:** I get values like these 
€
Œ

Comment: Hex values? Can you copy and paste some of them into your question please?

Comment: I get values like €
Œ

Comment: Well, that isn't hex, that's mumbo-jumbo. I suspect you are not operating at the correct clock rate. Do you have a crystal on your breadboard? If so what frequency is it? If not, how do you have the fuses configured?

Comment: Yes I have a crystal. It says 22.000C16 at the top. I thought I bought a 16MHz oscillator. Now I'm doubting. So you think it's the crystal oscillator's fault?

Comment: Well, if it worked on the Arduino board, but not on your breadboard. Make a simple test, like flashing an LED every ten seconds. Time how quickly it flashes on your breadboard.

Comment: Okay so I tried a simple flashing LED every second. And clearly it's not flashing every second. So the problem is the oscillator hmm? I'll buy a new one later and test it again to see if the problem persists. Thank you Nick

Comment: For what it is worth, with the clock rate wrong, you baud rate may also be wrong.

Comment: Also why the +5 in your calculation? Make tempC and reading ints as well

Comment: I haven't bought any 16 MHz crystal. What will I do? :(

Comment: You can configure the fuses to work from the 8 MHz internal oscillator, and then if you compile for 8 MHz Lilypad, that should give you the right baud rate.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `baud rate` of your serial monitor matches what you have set in your setup() function.  In the above code that is 9600.  If the baud rate is incorrect you typically get rubbish output in the serial monitor.

[image: Serial Monitor set at 9600 baud]

You may also want to change the Serial.print(tempC) to

```
Serial.println(tempC,2);
```

To get some decimal places.

As for the circuit ~

[image: Ricardo Sequeria's example Arduio & LM35]

- You don't need ARef connected.
- The LM35 VCC should be connected to Arduino 5V
- The LM35 GND to Arduino Gnd (any of them)
- Finally LM35 signal (Vout) to Arduino A0.

Comment: Thanks for answering but my baud rate is correct and adding ",2" did not help :(

Comment: Hanging ARef didn't change anything. The next three steps I did already. Nothing changed

Comment: @user5434720 - Your circuit looks like the diagram right?

Comment: No sir since I moved the MCU to a breadboard. I'm not using the Arduino board anymore

Answer (score 1):

> clearly it's not flashing every second.

Is it flashing about every .73 seconds? That would be the period you'd expect if you have a 22.000MHz crystal: period = (16/22 * 1.00 sec). (If so, that is a rather high over-clock rate for the chip but suggests just how hardy they really are.)

> I haven't bought any 16 MHz crystal. What will I do?

Buy a 16MHz crystal. That's the right fix. But you might (if I guessed correctly that you have a 22MHz crystal) - *might* - get away with trying a baud rate of (16/22) times your present baud rate, de-rating it to compensate for the clock rate. Be as precise as you can. You'll need to reprogram the chip with your Arduino board because the chip's bootloader expects a 16MHz clock.

Or, if it's not 22MHz, you could time a number of blinks (50 or 100), calculate the clock rate error, and re-calculate a baud rate the way I did above. Use a lower baud rate to start with; it is likely to be less affected by small timing errors.